# How to change multipolygon to polygon in R

Tags: r, r-sf

I bit confused, when i see geodata type in arcgis, my file is polygon. but when i analyze in R it be change to multipolygon. So i can't use `poly2nb`

before i use `st_cast(mynameshape, "MULTIPOLYGON") %>% st_cast("POLYGON")` but it isnt effect

how to convert multipolygon to polygon in rstudio or is there any other alternative than using poly2nb in doing analysis in geodata type multipolygon?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're using the `sf` package. The [`st_read()`](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/st_read.html) function has a parameter for this:

> `promote_to_multi` logical; in case of a mix of Point and MultiPoint, or of LineString and MultiLineString, or of Polygon and MultiPolygon, convert all to the Multi variety; defaults to TRUE

This is likely why your polygon is being read in as a multipolygon by default.

In your comment you note you are using `readOGR()` from the [`rgdal`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rgdal/versions/1.5-32/topics/readOGR) package. The advice in the 2022 edition of [Geocomputation with R](https://r.geocompx.org/spatial-class.html#why-simple-features) is:

> sf is now the go-to package for analysis of spatial vector data in R... Transitioning established packages and workflows away from legacy packages rgeos and rgdal takes time (Bivand 2021), but the process was given a sense of urgency by messages printed when they were loaded, which state that they “will be retired by the end of 2023”. This means that anyone still using these packages should “transition to sf/stars/terra functions using GDAL and PROJ at your earliest convenience”.

The easiest thing to do is simply:

```
my_shapefile <- st_read("path_to_file.shp", promote_to_multi = FALSE)
```

Comment: aaaaa... before for calling data i use setwd("C:/Users/HP/Downloads/SHP JAWA")
prov = readOGR(".", "Jawa_Barat") . . . so its automatic change into multipolygon?

Comment: What's the file type? In general it's better to use `st_read()` for vector data (including shapefiles), which will select the appropriate driver (e.g. rgdal), as many other geospatial packages are in the process of being deprecated.

Comment: but when i try p.nb <- poly2nb(my_shapefile) i get error ---> Error in wk_handle.wk_wkb(wkb, s2_geography_writer(oriented = oriented,  : 
  Loop 0 is not valid: Edge 0 is degenerate (duplicate vertex)

Comment: Try `p.nb <- st_make_valid(p.nb)` before `poly2nb()`. If that doesn't work, try toggling spherical geometry with `sf_use_s2(FALSE)`.